How to find the power factor of a component when the combined power factor and one other power factor is known?
Problem:
A 2000 volt-ampere with a power factor of 0.8 lagging is combined with 500 volt-amperes of
synchronous motors. If the overall power factor is 0.9 lagging, find the power factor of the
synchronous motors.
My attempt:

We want to find the angle in the second triangle. How do I do that? If only I had one more info about the last two triangles, I would have been able to find the angle of the second triangle.
ChatGPT told me to find the combined |S| by adding 2000 and 500, but that is just wrong. How do I proceed from here?

Are your loads connected in series?

@winny As you noticed, the problem statement does not make this clear. I assumed that they are in series.

As a bunch of words this (A 2000 volt-ampere with a power factor of 0.8 lagging) has little meaning. Do we assume it means a 2000 kVA load?

@Andyaka Your guess is as good as mine. I assumed they are loads.

It's a trigonometry problem; you know two sides of a triangle and can calculate one of its angles, so you can find all the other three parts and go from there.

@vir For the first triangle, I know everything. For the second triangle, I only know the length of the hypotenuse. For the third triangle, I only know the power factor angle.
If I knew even one more piece of info (like one more of the sides of the 2nd or 3rd triangle, I could have solved it easily, and it would have been an easy problem, but that is not the case here).

For a homework assignment, I assume anything is possible. In the real world, they would be in parallel.

@winny Would we be able to make the problem solvable if the loads were in parallel?

Much easier. Just calculate for each and superposition the results.

If they are in series, then they are like xmas lights.  All on, or all off. They are in parallel.

@winny I still can't figure out how to calculate the power factor of the 2nd triangle (which is what the question wants). Could you please help me?

Sure. You have an equation system. You have the real current for the first and the total for both. Now calculate the real current of the second one. After that same for the imaginary part.

@winny I know the real (average) power of the first load. I don't think I have the real current for the first load. Secondly, I only know the apparent power of the second load. I don't know how to calculate the current here because there is no source here (voltage/current). Could you please post an answer?

@winny Ignore my previous comment. I think I am onto something.

Phasors as vir posted is one way to solve it. I would just separate the real and imaginary currents and solve them separately.

As you correctly surmised, you can't add the magnitudes of complex power as ChatGPT says because they're vectors, but you can add them as vectors. 
Please forgive my drawing skills.

Edit: the difference of the two known angles, α, is 11.03 degrees. Then, use the law of sines to find β: 500/sin(α) = 2000/sin(β) so β = 50 degrees. The interior angles of a triangle add up to 180 degrees, so the third angle, γ, is 119 degrees. Use the law of sines one last time to recover |Stotal| = 2290kVA. From there, you have a right triangle and you should be able to finish up.

Thank you for your answer. But what will be the values of the angles? In other words,
$$|S_{\text{resultant}}|=\sqrt{2000^2+500^2+2 \cdot 2000 \cdot 500\cos{\alpha}}$$
What is the value of alpha here?

You can subtract the phase angle of the combined apparent power from the angle of the known apparent power. Then you have a triangle whose sides are the three apparent powers and you know one interior angle. The rest is trigonometry.

@tryingtobeastoic I've added some more to the answer.

Thank you so much

Hi! I had one more question. Is it possible to find out whether this power factor is lagging or leading. By that I mean, is it possible to know whether the current is leading or lagging?

You said in the question statement that the overall power factor is lagging.

Sorry, I should have made myself clearer. We know that the power factor of the first triangle is lagging and the third triangle is also lagging. Can we know whether the power factor of the second triangle is lagging or leading?

Yes, you will have to determine the power triangle for the additional load. You can do this by subtracting the real and reactive powers of the known load from the total load, which you now know.

Oh yeah I did that. $\cos(\theta)$ for the second triangle comes out to be $0.91$. Now, I just want to whether this power factor is lagging or leading.

Is reactive power a positive or negative quantity?

It's +287.933 VAR for the second triangle. So, the power factor is lagging. Thank you so much.
